# How do I slice a python string programmatically?

Tags: python, string

Very simple question, hopefully. So, in Python you can split up strings using indices as follows:

```
>>> a="abcdefg"
>>> print a[2:4]
cd
```

but how do you do this if the indices are based on variables? E.g.

```
>>> j=2
>>> h=4
>>> print a[j,h]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Comment: Use a colon, not a comma ... just like you would with numerical indices. :o)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to Bakkal's answer, here is how to manipulate slices programmatically, which is sometimes convenient:

```
a = 'abcdefg'
j=2;h=4
my_slice = slice(j,h) # you can pass this object around if you wish

a[my_slice] # -> cd
```

Answer (score 12):

It works you just have a typo in there, use `a[j:h]` instead of `a[j,h]`  :

```
>>> a="abcdefg"
>>> print a[2:4]
cd
>>> j=2
>>> h=4
>>> print a[j:h]
cd
>>>
```